# Loading binary file to richtextbox causes characters missing (visible in text-length)

Tags: c#, file-io, binary, richtextbox

attempt to load binary file with System.Default string conversion in to richtextbox in C#. The text-length of the richtextbox doesn't match the file length. It appears that the richtextbox skipped some characters from the file, but the file was loaded by the RTB to the end. The TextBox-Control can display the same file correctly. TextBox-Length and File-Length are identically. But what is the problem with the RTB? Why does the RTB skip inbetween some characters and the TextBox doesn't?
Is there a way to avoid this.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code 1 - wrong results, file characters in richtextbox missing
        richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\\test\\test.binary", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        //filelength: 3642938 Bytes
        //richtextbox-text-length: 3642876 Bytes  -> wrong text length!!! 62 Bytes somewhere missing

        //Code 2 - wrong results, file characters in richtextbox missing
        byte[] FileContent=System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\test\\test.binary");
        string FileString = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(FileContent);
        FileString = FileString.Replace((char)0, (char)32); //replace the Chr(0) nullbytes
        richTextBox1.Text = FileString; //assign the string to the text property of the RTB
        //filelength: 3642938 Bytes
        //richtextbox-text-length: 3642876 Bytes -> wrong text length!!! 62 Bytes somewhere missing

        //Code 2 with using TextBox Control
        textBox1.Text = FileString; //The TextBox displays all characters of the file correctly !!!
        //filelength: 3642938 Bytes
        //textbox-text-length: 3642938 Bytes -> correct text length
    }
```

With the RichTextStreamType.RichText in use will be thrown exception (see test code below)

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code 1 - wrong results, file characters in richtextbox missing
        //richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\\test\\test.binary", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        try
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\\test\\test.binary", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText); //throws exception
            //Invalid Fileformat - Type: System Argument Exception.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear(); //clear the clipboard before filling it
            Clipboard.SetText(ex.Message); //set error message to clipboard
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.Data.ToString()); //display the error information
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "/s"); //shutdown windows on error to prevent further data damage
            Application.Exit(); //exit application on error if it wasn't exited already
        }
        //filelength: 3642938 Bytes
        //richtextbox-text-length: 3642876 Bytes  -> wrong text length!!! 62 Bytes somewhere missing
```

}

with the "RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText" property the RTB stays empty and the user interface
hangs with endless loading.

Comment: what is the result when you load it as RichText? `richTextBox1.LoadFile(fileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);`

Comment: change RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText to RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText to avoid the Invalid File format.